# Sometimes Jcomponents are not visible until mouse hovering

Tags: java, hover, jbutton, mouse, visible

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);

JButton button = new JButton();

button.setSize(30, 30);
button.setLocation(30, 30);

panel.add(button);
```

I dont know but sometimes button appeares itself (as i understand it has to) and sometimes button does not appear until mouse hovers it. Can you explain please is it bug or i do something wrong.

Comment: I noticed that if i add line

Comment: I noticed that if i add line button.setBorderPainted(false); my button appears all the time.

Comment: JFYI, you may edit your comments for 5 minutes after posting them; you may also delete your comments at any time should you find them unnecessary. To inline code as `button.setBorderPainted(false);` enclose it with backtick ` symbol.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Answer (score 0):

The method

> repaint()

is a solution